# Limiting value of the sum of two sequences of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, limits, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. Is the following true?

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 + \cdots + np_n}{p_n + 2p_{n-1} + 3p_{n-2} + \cdots + np_{1}} = 2
$$

**Note**: The [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) implies that the ratio is $\ge 1$.

**Update**: Extending Yves Daoust's solution, we can show that following hold

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{p_1 + 2^a p_2 + 3^a p_3 + \cdots + n^a p_n}{p_n + 2^a p_{n-1} + 3^a p_{n-2} + \cdots + n^a p_{1}} = a + 1
$$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{p_1^a + 2p_2^a + 3p_3^a + \cdots + np_n^a}{p_n^a + 2p_{n-1}^a + 3p_{n-2}^a + \cdots + np_{1}^a} = a + 1
$$

Comment: Should the last term in the denominator be $n p_1$?

Comment: Do you mean multiplication by $a.b$? Then replace the . by \cdot .

Comment: By stolz cesaro the limit is equal to $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)p_{n+1}} {1\cdot (p_{n+1}-p_n)+2\cdot(p_n-p_{n-1})+\cdots + n\cdot (p_2-p_1)+(n+1)p_1}$ though not sure if it helps.

Comment: @MartinR Yes correct

Comment: You could replace $p_n $ with $n\log n$ then $p_{n+1}-p_n $ is asymptotically equal to $\log(n+1)$ so you want to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2\log(n+1)} {\log(n+1)+2\log(n)+\cdots n\log 2+2(n+1)}$. Wolfram says this indeed equals to $2$ though replacing $p_n$ with $n\log n$ might be questionable.

Comment: @kingW3: That looks like a promising approach to me. Note that the denominator simplifies to $p_1 + p_2 + \ldots + p_{n+1}$.

Comment: @kingW3: Using Cesaro-Stolz once more gives $\frac{(n+1)p_{n+1}-np_n}{p_{n+1}}$.

Comment: @kingW3: $p_n=n\log n$ is true asymptotically and there is no cancellation, so this is legit. For rigor you can write $p_n=n\log n+o(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Prime Number theorem,

$$p_n\sim n\log n.$$

Then approximating the sums by integrals,

$$\frac{\int_1^n x^2\log x\,dx}{\int_1^n (n-x)x\log x\,dx}\sim\frac{\frac{n^3}3\log n}{(\frac{n^3}2-\frac{n^3}3)\log n}\to2.$$