# Can we rearrange primes to make this ratio converge to any real?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, limits, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime and let $q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_n$ be any rearrangement of the first $n$ primes. Using the rearrangement inequality and the [solution to this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336975/limiting-value-of-the-sum-of-two-sequences-of-prime-numbers?noredirect=1#comment6869484_3336975), we can prove that

$$
1 \le \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 + \cdots + np_n}{q_1 + 2q_2 + 3q_3 + \cdots + nq_n} \le 2
$$

I was wondering if we can make the above ratio arbitrarily close to any real number in the interval $(1,2)$ by choosing a suitable rearrangement of the first $n$ primes i.e.

> **Question**: Let $\alpha, 1 \le \alpha \le 2$ be any real. Does there always  exist a rearrangement such that,
>
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 + \cdots +
>  np_n}{q_1 + 2q_2 + 3q_3 + \cdots + nq_n} = \alpha$$

Comment: I don't understand; if $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ is a rearrangement of the first $n$ primes, and $q_1,\ldots,q_{n+1}$ is a rearrangement of the first $n+1$ primes, then $q_{n+1}=p_{n+1}$. So then the limit equals $1$.

Comment: Also, in the question in blockquotes, what is the use of $\epsilon$? You might as well just write
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 + \cdots +
 np_n}{q_1 + 2q_2 + 3q_3 + \cdots + nq_n} = \alpha.$$
But as I suggested above, it is unclear to me what the $n$-th term of the sequence (that you are taking the limit of) is. Are you taking a different rearrangement for each $n$? Because then denoting them all with the same $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ is a bit confusing.

Comment: $q_1,...,q_{n+1}$ is a rearrangement of the first $n+1$ primes and it need not necessarily preserve the same arrangement for the first $n$ terms. Otherwise we will always have $q_i = p_i$ hence no rearrangement. Its like reshuffling the entire deck of card when ever you add one more card to the deck. Yes $\epsilon$ can be removed.

Comment: Can I suggest then to ask instead for a sequence of *permutations* $\sigma_n\in S_n$, for each $n\in\Bbb{N}$, such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 + \cdots +  np_n}{p_{\sigma_n(1)}+2p_{\sigma_n(2)}+3p_{\sigma_n(3)}+\cdots+np_{\sigma_n(n)}}=\alpha,$$
or to avoid clutter in the indices, you could equivalently ask for such a sequence such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 + \cdots +  np_n}{\sigma_n(1)p_{1}+\sigma_n(2)p_{2}+\sigma_n(3)p_{3}+\cdots+\sigma_n(n)p_{n}}=\alpha.$$

Comment: @Servaes Can you edit the quesiton by copying the code from your comment?

Comment: Tip: You can right-click the math and select `Show Math As -> TeX Commands` and copy the code yourself. (No snarky tone intended; just letting you know in case you were not aware of this feature.)

Comment: Have you tried solving for some examples? For example, how can we make it converge to $\alpha=1.5$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

1. The idea is to define parameter $t$, such that the limit takes values in $[1,2]$ depending on $t$.
2. Turns out the primes $p_n$ are not special, the problem is equivalent if we take either $n$ or $n\log n$.

> For $t \in[0,1]$ and $g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$, define:
>
> $$
> f(t, g):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac
> {\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot g(k)}
> {\sum_{k=1}^{n - t n}k\cdot g(k)+\sum_{k= n - t n + 1}^{n}k\cdot g((2-t)n-k+1)}
> $$
>
> For $g(x)=p_x$ we have your problem, where $p_x$ is the $x$th prime.

The general **idea** here being that, first $(t\times100)\%$ of terms in denominator are arranged in reverse, compared to the numerator.

Trivially, $f(0,g)=1$, for any $g$, as we have the same numerator and denominator.

We know that $f(1, p_x)=2$ which was [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3337069) in your other question you linked.

> We can estimate $p_x\sim x\log x$ like it was done in the linked
> question, and discussed in comments there.

Interestingly, for $g(x)=x$ and for $g(x)=x\log x$, the limit converges in both cases to:

$$
f(t)=\frac{2}{2-t^3}
$$

> Turns out $f(t,x)\sim f(t,x \log x)\sim f(t, p_x)$. Similar case was
> with [one of your other
> questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/406633/318073).

The first two limits I computed with wolfram alpha (Mathematica):

```
ClearAll[g, f, t, n, k];
g[n_] := n Log[n];
f[t_] := Limit[Sum[k*g[k], {k, 1, n}]/(Sum[k*g[k], {k, 1, n - t n}] + Sum[k*g[(n - k + n - t n + 1)], {k, n - t n + 1, n}]), n -> Infinity];
f[t]
```

And we are done since:

1. The $f(t,x)=f(t, x\log x)=2/(2-t^3)$, depending on $t\in[0,1]$, takes real values in
   $[1,2]$
2. We can show in a similar way to the question I linked, that $f(t,x)= f(t,x \log x)= f(t, p_x)$

Comment: I have a similar derivation with a slightly more general form; but this property will be exhibited by any sequence $a_n$ if the the sequence of ratios $a_r/a_n, r = 1,2,\ldots,n$ approach uniform distribution in $(0,1)$.